# How do I print out the dictionary in another menu

Tags: c#

I am new to this so pardon me. I have created a menu so that if I input 1, the program will do this set of code for 1 and so on. I am not sure how to "move" the dictionary I have created after entering option 1 into option 2. Help would be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;`
using System.Linq;

namespace PokemonPocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //PokemonMaster list for checking pokemon evolution availability.    
            List<PokemonMaster> pokemonMasters = new List<PokemonMaster>(){
            new PokemonMaster("Pikachu", 2, "Raichu"),
            new PokemonMaster("Eevee", 3, "Flareon"),
            new PokemonMaster("Charmander", 1, "Charmeleon")
            };
            // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
            PokemonMenu();
        }
        static void PokemonMenu()
        {   //Part 1 - Creating the menu for user input
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
            Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
            Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
            Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
            Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
            Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");
            char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            if (menu == '1'){
                Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                myDictionary.Add("FirstName", "John");
                myDictionary.Add("LastName", "Walter");
                PokemonMenu();


            }
             if (menu == '2') {
                 foreach (var v in myDictionary)
                     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", v.Key, v.Value));
                     PokemonMenu();
             }
            if (menu == 'Q'){
                Console.WriteLine("App exited!");
                Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: the "foreach (var v in myDictionary)" will cause an error and im not sure why too

Comment: myDictionary is declared inside the if block for `menu == 1` so it is not accessible inside the if block of `menu == 2`

Comment: i dont really understand, could you explain how come its not accessible?

Comment: A useful term here is "Scope". The dictionary declared in your "if(menu == '1')" is only valid inside that scope (inside the curly brackets of that "if" where it was declared) and not accessible inside the scope of your other curly brackets. Try searching around for C# scope rules for further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest uisng *loop* instead of *recursion* (i.e. calling `PokemonMenu()` within itself):

```
static void PokemonMenu() {
  // From now on myDictionary is available for any menu option 
  var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      
  while (true) { // <- loop until exit option (key 'Q') is pressed
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
    Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
    Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
    Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
    Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
    Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");

    char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    if (menu == '1') {
      // We, probably, want to add just once
      if (myDictionary.Count <= 0) { 
        myDictionary.Add("FirstName", "John");
        myDictionary.Add("LastName", "Walter");
      }
      else
        Console.WriteLine($"You have {myDictionary.Count} in your pocket.");
    }
    else if (menu == '2') 
      foreach (var v in myDictionary)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", v.Key, v.Value));
    else if (menu == 'Q') {
      Console.WriteLine("App exited!");

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this one works for me, but how come you left this comment at " if (menu == '1') " that want to add once?

Comment: @user15982865: if user contantly choose option `1`, you, probably, want to add into `myDictionary` just *once* in order not to have key conflict (all keys must be distinct)

Comment: To address the issue, add or replace the entry with `myDictionary["FirstName"] = "John";` or re-create the dictionary from scratch.

Comment: ah ok I see now

Answer (score 0):

Because your "myDictionary" is defined in if (menu == '1') scope. You move out if statement.Also You should change "myDictionary" as Global variable.

```
class Program
{
    //Global Variable
    static Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //PokemonMaster list for checking pokemon evolution availability.    
        //List<PokemonMaster> pokemonMasters = new List<PokemonMaster>(){
        //new PokemonMaster("Pikachu", 2, "Raichu"),
        //new PokemonMaster("Eevee", 3, "Flareon"),
        //new PokemonMaster("Charmander", 1, "Charmeleon")
        //};
        // Use "Environment.Exit(0);" if you want to implement an exit of the console program
        PokemonMenu();
    }
    static void PokemonMenu()
    {   //Part 1 - Creating the menu for user input
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Pokemon Pocket App!");
        Console.WriteLine("(1). Add Pokemon to my pocket");
        Console.WriteLine("(2). List Pokemon(s) in my pocket");
        Console.WriteLine("(3). Check if I can evolve Pokemon");
        Console.WriteLine("(4). Evolve Pokemon\n");
        Console.Write("Please only enter [1,2,3,4] or Q to exit:");
        char menu = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        //You can't define here because ever PokemonMenu() call will create new empty dictionary. 
        //Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (menu == '1')
        {
            //This is under if statmenet/ if scope so only you can reach in this scope {}.
            //Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            myDictionary.Add("FirstName", "John");
            myDictionary.Add("LastName", "Walter");
            PokemonMenu();
        }
        if (menu == '2')
        {
            foreach (var v in myDictionary)
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", v.Key, v.Value));
            PokemonMenu();
        }
        if (menu == 'Q')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("App exited!");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```